# Pull all files added in the last 30 minutes on AWS S3 Bucket

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, .net-core

I have to pull files from the S3 bucket added in the last 30 min using C#, currently, I'm pulling all files and running the loop on S3Objects, but this is like running a loop on millions of records. Is that possible to submit a request to S3 to get files added in the last 30 mins?
Here is my current code:

```
var _req = new ListObjectsV2Request
{
    BucketName = "sample1",
    Prefix = /testExport/test,
    MaxKeys = int.MaxValue //get all in the last 30 min files
};

var lastmodifiedDt = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-30);
var response = await _s3Client.ListObjectsV2Async(_req);
foreach (var file in response.S3Objects)
{
    if (file.LastModified.ToUniversalTime() >= lastmodifiedDt)
    {
        //do rest of the process.
    }   
}
```

Comment: There is no underlying API to list objects based off a filter other than a shared prefix.  If you need such functionality, you'll need to create and maintain a separate [metadata database](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/building-and-maintaining-an-amazon-s3-metadata-index-without-servers/) that you can query.

Comment: @AnonCoward , each file contains the DateTime stamp, is that possible to pass the prefix filter based on the filename?
e.g. 
/testExport/test/EMSSEExt_20230207-20230314094159.csv

Comment: If the files are created in the regular interval, you can use a prefix filter, and that too for 1-hour intervals because if you use 30mins internal, you have to call S3 API for each and every minute, that's not desirable. However, if you use a lambda function to implement this functionality, you can set an s3 trigger where you can configure batch window time for 30mins, and it will let you accumulate all s3 files events in SQS for 30mins and then it will trigger the lambda function.

Comment: You could request, say, the last two hours by requesting all items that start with "/testExport/test/EMSSEExt_20230207-2023031408" and  "/testExport/test/EMSSEExt_20230207-2023031409", then filtering down to the last 30 minutes in code.  Which technically, this would work, I'd still rather implement a metadata database if I was asked to implement this.

Comment: Can you tell us more about _WHY_ you want to do this? The reason I ask is that your situation might be suitable for triggering an AWS Lambda function automatically whenever a new object is created. The Lambda function could run your "do rest of process" code on that new object automatically as soon as the object arrives, rather than waiting to process files every 30 minutes. The result is a much faster response and a similar amount of total processing.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I needed to download and upload to other side FTP servers. The S3 gets uploaded with files anytime during the day, and my middleware worker will check every 30 min if new files are uploaded to S3 and transmit those files to the FTP server. I can create an API, which can be called by the Lambda function whenever a file is added to S3. Can you please share an example of how to execute lambda on a new object to S3?

Comment: This [Event Notifications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/EventNotifications.html) seems to be promising. If I manage to receive a new object notification to API which contains the object name, then I can create [GetObjectRequest](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/M_Amazon_S3_AmazonS3_GetObject.htm) to download the file.

Comment: Yes, you can configure an Amazon S3 Event to trigger an AWS Lambda function. Your code in the function could call the API. The event will provide the Bucket and Key of the object that was created. Thus, you could trigger the middleware immediately after the file is created, rather than having to check every 30 minutes. If no files are received, nothing needs to run. There are plenty of code examples on StackOverflow, just search for "s3 event lambda" and your preferred programming language.